# COM port access via website

Tags: asp.net, serial-port

I have been given the task of creating a web application that will communicate with an RS-232 barcode scanner, an RS-232 customer display, print to a receipt printer and open a cash drawer.
I have VS2012 and was going to write the application in ASP.NET.
HOWEVER, through what I have read in this forum, it's not that easy to communicate with RS-232 from a website.
The RS-232 devices are connected to the client's machine and NOT the server.

What can I use to communicate with these devices if it's a web application?

Comment: Someone is playing a joke on you. A web site lives on the server, and these RS232 devices live on some client computer running a browser. You can't touch the client computer from the browser!

Comment: Thanks John, Its not a joke, although I wish It was. I was told Java could access it or Silver light. Unfortunately i am not sure where to start.

Comment: Yes, Java or SlverLight. No, HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Hi John, Iv been looking on the net and found that there is something called pos.dot. Can this be used in ASP.NET ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it. The one time I read anything about it, I thought it was software to _run_ a POS terminal. It was an OEM product.

Answer (score 0):

A signed Java applet can access local hardware. So can ActiveX components, and probably silver light, too. A web page can communicate with these things using JavaScript.

You are probably targeting windows clients only, so likely you can use a commercially available POS ActiveX component, if there are any.

Comment: Thanks Joni, it is a very small POS application im doing and I cannot find any POS ActiveX's that I can use. As far as I knew, ActiveX will only work on IE. Im a desktop / ASP.NET programmer not JAVA or Silverlight. I was thinking, as a work around, that If I write a small windows service that will communicate with the COM PORTS. Have this application/Service have an open socket. Then from the website, I somehow send a socket of information to the client application to say print on a customer display.

Comment: To me it sounded OK but I cannot get my head around how to get a barcode scanner to communicate back to the web. See, my desktop application can have a trigger event to send the incoming comport information out through the socket, but I dont want my web application sat in a loop waiting, I also want a trigger to pick it up.What do you think

Comment: If you can install a service on the client machine, why not make a normal desktop application?

Comment: Hi Joni, the client application is a work around. It actually needs to be a full web application.